# Trouble Displaying navbar [Bootstrap]

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm having some trouble displaying the nav bar with Bootstrap. I've reviewed my code, but am not sure what the problem is.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="navbar navbar-inverse"></div>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </body>
  <html>
```

If this helps, I stored the index.html file within the dist folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse"></div>
```

To

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse"></nav>
```

Edit, fixed:

Environmental issue due to installing bootstrap via npm.
Declaring `<script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js">‌​</script>`before `<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>` should fix this..

Comment: Hey Oliver,

I changed the tag to nav, but it's still showing an empty page.

Comment: Which browser are you testing with? Are you getting any errors (F12/Developer tools)?

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome. It's asking me to install Tether.io for tooltips

Comment: Is Tether typically needed for Bootstrap installation? I've walked through a couple of tutorials, but didn't see anything about this.

Comment: Which source did you use for downloading bootstrap?

Comment: I installed Bootstrap globally w/ npm

Comment: Okay, and do you have the following paths within the dist folder:

    `css/bootstrap.css`
    `js/bootstrap.js`

Comment: yup, I do. Within the dist folder, there's a css folder with bootstrap.css

Comment: Your example works fine in a sandbox, so it feels like a environmental issue. Same results with an alternative browser?

Comment: I tried Firefox, and it's also showing a blank webpage.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by environment issue?

Comment: It sounds like there's an issue in the paths somewhere. Firefox providing any errors? You can see the example works fine here: https://www.bootply.com/M9ABjuuD15

Comment: Error: Bootstrap tooltips require Tether (http://tether.io/)
The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

Comment: Declare `<script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>` before `<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>`

Comment: Hey Oliver, you were right about the environment issue.

I downloaded Bootstrap (without npm), and the nav bar showed up fine.

I'm not sure what happened there, but am glad it's working now.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

This was an environment issue. After reinstalling Bootstrap, the nav bar was displayed.